# PagerDuty assignments list empty

Tags: python

How can I get "assignments" key of the incidents in PagerDuty? I have a python script which returns info on particular incident, but the list with assignments is empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json
API_KEY = 'iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii'

# incident ID
ID = 'PPPPP'

def get_incident():
url = 'https://api.pagerduty.com/incidents/{id}'.format(id=ID)
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2',
    'Authorization': 'Token token={token}'.format(token=API_KEY)
}

params = {
    'include': 'assignees',
    'time_zone': 'Europe/Sofia'
}


r = requests.get(url, headers=headers,data=json.dumps(params))
print ('Status Code: {code}'.format(code=r.status_code))
print (r.json())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_incident()
```

In their documentation [here](https://v2.developer.pagerduty.com/v2/page/api-reference#!/Incidents/get_incidents) there are entries for that key, see on the picture bellow:

[image: picture]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should check out ngDesk instead as its totally free and has more features then pager duty. You can check it out here https://www.ngdesk.com

Comment: I can use the code you shared to query for an incident and get it's assignments. Can you double check that the incident of the ID you are querying has an assignee on it through the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Based on experimentation, it appears that assignments are only populated while an incident is still active. I just queried `/incidents/id` for an incident in the `triggered` state and in the `resolved` state, the `triggered` one shows an assignment while the `resolved` one does not.

It's kind of frustrating, because I want to look at the `LogEntry`s for an incident via their API and I haven't figured that out yet.

The `alert_counts` field always seems to contain zeros too, which doesn't make any sense.